# Pass ternary operator to parameter of a function

Tags: c++, arguments, conditional-operator, function-call

Can I pass ternary operator to parameter of a function?

```
int test(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a+b+c;
}

int nn = 0;
int a = test(1, 1 | (2 ? nn : 0), 1); // test(1, 1 | 0, 1)

n = 1;
a = test(1, 1 | (2 ? nn : 0), 1); // test(1, 1 | 2, 1)
```

Comment: What issue did you face when trying this?

Comment: `warning: enum constant in boolean context [-Wint-in-bool-context]`

Comment: Did you check each piece, or did you jump to a conclusion? *(An example of testing each piece would be moving complex expressions out of a function's argument list. For example, you might try `int parameter = 1 | (2 ? nn : 0); int a = test(1, parameter, 1);`.)* Jumping to conclusions tends to be counter-productive.

Answer (score 4):

You are not passing the ternary operator. You are passing the value of evaluation of the expression with the ternary operator.

You may use any expression as an argument that produces a value the type of which does not contradict to the type of the corresponding parameter.